# import org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainFactory Unresolved reference: JavaToolchainFactory

Tags: kotlin, gradle

So I'm trying to figure out how to compile my android app with an open source kotlin project https://github.com/mobile-dev-inc/dadb using gradle. I'm able to run `./gradlew assemble` in both of them successfully, however I want to have a root directory that can treat them as subprojects to compile. I think the complication arises from the fact that `dadb` has its own subproject called `dadb`, which makes it a bit more tricky. This is my current error that I'm getting trying to compile from the root directory:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/tron/AndroidStudioProjects/cookie/dadb/dadb/build.gradle.kts' line: 4

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 04: import org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainFactory
                                                    ^ Unresolved reference: JavaToolchainFactory

  Line 29: val toolchainFactory = objects.newInstance(JavaToolchainFactory::class.java)
                                          ^ Not enough information to infer type variable T
```

This is my root `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "cookie"
include(":app")
include(":dadb")
include(":dadb:dadb")
```

This is my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
}
```

This is `dadb/dadb`'s `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.gradle.internal.jvm.inspection.DefaultJvmMetadataDetector
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem
import org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.DefaultToolchainSpec
import org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainFactory
import org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainInput

plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    id("com.vanniktech.maven.publish")
    `java-library`
    id("com.palantir.graal") version "0.9.0"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.5"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api("com.squareup.okio:okio:2.10.0")
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    testImplementation("com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1")
}

val toolchainFactory = objects.newInstance(JavaToolchainFactory::class.java)
val metadataDetector = objects.newInstance(DefaultJvmMetadataDetector::class.java)

graal {
    graalVersion("21.0.0.2")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.nativeTestCompile {
    dependsOn(tasks.extractGraalTooling)
}

graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        all {
            buildArgs.add("-H:+EnableAllSecurityServices")
            javaLauncher.set(provider {
                val output = tasks.extractGraalTooling.get().outputs.files.singleFile
                val javaHome = if (OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX) output.resolve("Contents/Home") else output
                val metadata = metadataDetector.getMetadata(javaHome)
                if (!metadata.isValidInstallation) {
                    throw RuntimeException(metadata.errorMessage)
                }
                val spec = objects.newInstance(DefaultToolchainSpec::class.java).apply {
                    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(java.targetCompatibility.majorVersion))
                }
                val javaToolchain = toolchainFactory.newInstance(javaHome, JavaToolchainInput(spec))
                javaToolchain.get().javaLauncher
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is dadb's `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
rootProject.name = "dadb"
include("dadb")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainFactory` is not present in recent versions of Gradle, hence why you are having a problem.

I see that DADB is built with Gradle 7.2 ([GitHub](https://github.com/mobile-dev-inc/dadb/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties)) so it is clearly compatible with that version. If you downgrade to version 7.2 then it should compile.